# What is $\{1, 3, 5, 7 ,9, 11, 13, 15 \} / \{ 1, 3, 9, 11\}$?

Tags: group-theory

I want to know how to perform division (I don't know whether division is the proper terminology here) over group. (not a single element by another  element.)

What is $\{1, 3, 5, 7 ,9, 11, 13, 15 \} / \{ 1, 3, 9, 11\}$?
The group is modulo 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is NOT division. It is a **quotient group** $\Bbb{Z}^{\times}_{16}/\langle 3 \rangle$, where the "elements" of this quotient group are "cosets". For a group $G$ with a normal subgroup $H$, the quotient group is defined as 
$$G/H=\{gH \, | \, g \in G\}.$$

Using this we get,
$$\Bbb{Z}^{\times}_{16}/\langle 3 \rangle=\left\{a\langle 3 \rangle \, | \, a \in \Bbb{Z}^{\times}_{16}\right\}=\{\langle 3 \rangle, 5\langle 3 \rangle\}=\{\left\{1,3,9,11\right\}, \,\, \left\{5,15,13,7\right\}\}$$